# Read pdf file line by line using java

Tags: java, pdf, doc

How to read pdf file line by line using java, And write the lines in .txt and .doc file?
Please mention the required .jar for the program.

Comment: This is something you need to write in a search engine, not here.

Comment: No !I do not find answer as my requirement. I get the answer in c++.

Comment: I do not also found how to write the line in txt file. I have solve the problem ,but can not read or write the data line by line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

```
try{
PDDocument document = null; 
document = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));
document.getClass();
if( !document.isEncrypted() ){
    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
    stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
    PDFTextStripper Tstripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String st = Tstripper.getText(document);
    System.out.println("Text:"+st);
}
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can download it from [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi)

Comment: The snippet does not process the PDF line by line.